# Itext java pdfptableevent rounded corners background multiple pages

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable, pdfpages

I am using itext 4.2 java to generate pdf and want to have rounded corners with background color and I am able to accomplish it as well.
I face one issue the first column was alone getting rounded corner and background so inorder to fix it ,I need to add one empty row with total number of columns in a table and after adding it table showed proper rounded corners and background.

The issue which I am facing now is ,  pdfptableevent is not applying on multiple pages properly.
Table has many records and it does split on multiple pages and the behavior is only first column of the row is getting rounded with its background color. Rest of the columns are not applying pdfptableevent and one extra page is getting added in last page.
may be we can ignore the extra last page.

Please advise how to resolve issue with pdfptableevent which has many records spliting in multiple pages .

I tried using setkeeptogether true it gives more problems.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code and the pdf screenshots on what you need and what you are getting

Comment: One class extending pdfptableevent and get basecanvas use roundrectangle with 4 radius and apply the page event to table with 100s of records. As we have many  records the table spits in multiple pages .only 1st column  in a table gets rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

I used multiple pdfpcellevent instead of pdfptableevent to round cells instead of table.